# How to prevent python script from exiting when it hits [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Tags: python

I have a python script and I'm using a `while loop` to loop forever, my script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket,select,time,base64,os,sys,re,datetime

def on_outbounddata(self):
        print "ON_OUTBOUNDDATA"
        netdata = self.netdata
        if netdata.find('HTTP/1.') ==0:
            ms = re.search(r"\^s(\d+)\^", payload)
            if ms:
                print "Sleeping for " + ms.group(1) + "ms"
                dec = int(ms.group(1)) / float(1000)
                time.sleep(dec)
                print self.request[self.s]
                try:
                    self.channel_[self.s].send(self.request[self.s])
                    self.request[self.s]=''
                except ValueError:
                    print "self.s is not in the list (on_outbounddata)"
                    pass
            netdata='HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established\r\n\r\n'
        try:
            self.channel[self.s].send(netdata)
        except Exception, e:
            print e
def main_loop(self):
    while 1:
        # Do stuff
        self.on_outbounddata()
        # Do stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server = TheServer('0.0.0.0', listen)
    try:
        server.main_loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Ctrl C - Stopping server"
```

The problem is that even though I have a while loop, sometimes the script will exit on its own when it encounters the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/socks", line 206, in <module>
    server.main_loop()
  File "/usr/bin/socks", line 121, in main_loop
    self.on_outbounddata()
  File "/usr/bin/socks", line 190, in on_outbounddata
    self.channel_[self.s].send(self.request[self.s])
socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

I want my script to continue even though it excounters this exception `socket.error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle a broken pipe (SIGPIPE) in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180095/how-to-handle-a-broken-pipe-sigpipe-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use a blank except policy, but that is a bad practice typically.  It would look like `

```
try:
     self.channel[self.s].send(netdata)
except Exception, e:
     print e
except:
     code for blanket exception
```

`  Check out [How to handle a broken pipe (SIGPIPE) in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180095/how-to-handle-a-broken-pipe-sigpipe-in-python) it seems to be a very similar to your problem.

Comment: if it's bad practice why post it as a solution?

Comment: It will keep his program from throwing exceptions but in doing so he may end up eating other exceptions.  There is a more elegant solution in the link I posted, but OP may not need that solution if he is trying to do something quick and dirty.  However I wanted to make sure he was aware of both ways.

Comment: He/she's clearly aware. They use try/except several times throughout their script.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide a working example, so the answer can be only little bit theoretical.
Try to make exception handling to every point where exception can happen.

E.g.

```
while 1:
    # Do stuff
    self.on_outbounddata()
```

No exception handling here. Only partly inside of the function.

Also here you do not handle errors:

```
    try:
        server.main_loop()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Ctrl C - Stopping server"
```

Here you only handle one type of exception:

```
        try:
            self.channel_[self.s].send(self.request[self.s])
            self.request[self.s]=''
        except ValueError:
            print "self.s is not in the list (on_outbounddata)"
            pass
```

Comment: How do I handle any kind of exception ? so it's not just one

Comment: Use multiple except lines. Simple example from python docs (check the example with multiple except lines): https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions