# Python socket errno 32 broken pipe

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to send a message over TCP/IP via python, the first message has been received but when I try to send another one it returns: "socket error32 broken pipe"

my code:

```
import socket
from RPi import GPIO
from time import sleep

TCP_IP = '192.168.178.29'
TCP_PORT = 45335
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

clk = 17
dt = 18

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(clk, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(dt, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

counter = 0
clkLastState = GPIO.input(clk)

try:
      while True:
            clkState = GPIO.input(clk)
            dtState = GPIO.input(dt)
            if clkState != clkLastState:
                    if dtState != clkState:
                            counter += 1
                    else:
                            counter -= 1
                    s.send(str(counter))
                    print counter
            clkLastState = clkState
            sleep(0.01)
finally:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

I tried searching for this issue but I couldn't find a solution, the socket is still open when I try to send the second message.
Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: The other side closed the connection, maybe? Have you used a sniffer to look at the traffic?

Comment: Yes I did, I used packet sender

Comment: Can you show server code? One issue is TCP is not a message-based protocol. You send counter 0123456789, etc. and it can be read as one long number if you don’t have a protocol for determining message breaks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe *SIGPIPE* error :

> Your server process has received a SIGPIPE writing to a socket. This
>   usually happens when you write to a socket fully closed on the other
>   (client) side. This might be happening when a client program doesn't
>   wait till all the data from the server is received and simply closes a
>   socket (using close function).
>
> In a C program you would normally try setting to ignore SIGPIPE signal
>   or setting a dummy signal handler for it. In this case a simple error
>   will be returned when writing to a closed socket. In your case a
>   python seems to throw an exception that can be handled as a premature
>   disconnect of the client.

[How to prevent errno 32 broken pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866792/how-to-prevent-errno-32-broken-pipe)

[How to handle a broken pipe (SIGPIPE) in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180095/how-to-handle-a-broken-pipe-sigpipe-in-python?rq=1)