# Testing for a closed socket

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming

I'm trying to test for a closed socket that has been gracefully closed by the peer without incurring the latency hit of a double send to induce a `SIGPIPE`.

One of the assumptions here is that the socket if closed was gracefully closed by the peer immediately after it's last write / send.  Actual errors like a premature close are dealt with else where in the code.

If the socket is still open, there will be 0 or more bytes data which I don't actually want to pull out of the socket buffer yet.

I was thinking that I could call `int ret = recv(sockfd, buf, 1, MSG_DONTWAIT | MSG_PEEK);` to determine if the socket is still connected.  If it's connected but there's no data in the buffer I'll get a return of `-1` with `errno == EAGAIN` and return the sockfd for reuse.  If it's been gracefully closed by the peer I'll get `ret == 0` and open a new connection.

I've tested this and it **seems** to work.  However, I suspect there is a small window between when I recv the last bit of my data and when the peer `FIN` arrives in which I could get a false-positive `EAGAIN` from my test `recv`.

Is this going to bite me, or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: An alternate way is select() (or poll()), since it can control a fd both rfor read and for write, but I dont know if it actually solve your problem about the FIN timing.

Comment: @Giuseppe:  No, I don't think select would solve the timing problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so I ran some more tests and this is what I found.

I set my client up to send `HTTP/1.1 Connection: close` messages to the server causing the server to call close after it's last write of data.  When my client finished reading data from a GET transaction it would test the socket to see if it was still open using the above method and then attempt to issue another GET.

What I found is that approximately 30% of the time my test would occur before the server's `FIN` arrived leading to false-positives and failed operations.

Probably the only way to make this reasonably reliable, say close to 99% would be to introduce artificial delays related to the connection latency between the last read and the attempted socket reuse - however, that would pretty much murder performance.

So, I have to conclude that while this tool is useful, it's only marginally so.

Comment: +1 : interesting tests. One can understand why in telecom 90% of the code is for managing exceptional behavior :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you control the other end? The most reliable way to perform a "clean" shut down of a socket is for the other end to send a "goodbye" message of some sort.

Comment: No, I don't control the other end.  However, the other end **should** always send a application level message indicating that they are closing from their end.  It's just that in the real world that doesn't always happen.  I could treat it like a regular error, but I would like to try and actively catch it most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

(Slightly "off topic", sorry). Perhaps [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly) may be helpful four you. It still doesn't answer to you "FIN" question, but may help you to react in a more easy way to the peer shutdown while your program is sending.

Bye