# TCP client-server SIGPIPE

Tags: tcp, sigpipe

I am designing and testing a client server program based on TCP sockets(Internet domain). Currently , I am testing it on my local machine and not able to understand the following about SIGPIPE.

*. SIGPIPE appears quite randomly. Can it be deterministic?

The first tests involved single small(25 characters) send operation from client and corresponding receive at server. The same code, on the same machine runs successfully or not(SIGPIPE) totally out of my control. The failure rate is about 45% of times(quite high). So, can I tune the machine in any way to minimize this.

**. The second round of testing was to send 40000 small(25 characters) messages from the client to the server(1MB of total data) and then the server responding with the total size of data it actually received. The client sends data in a tight loop and there is a SINGLE receive call at the server. It works only for a maximum of 1200 bytes of total data sent and again, there are these non deterministic SIGPIPEs, about 70% times now(really bad).

Can some one suggest some improvement in my design(probably it will be at the server). The requirement is that the client shall be able to send over medium to very high amount of data (again about 25 characters each message) after a single socket connection has been made to the server.
I have a feeling that multiple sends against a single receive will always be lossy and very inefficient. Shall we be combining the messages and sending in one send() operation only. Is that the only way to go?

Answer (score 9):

SIGPIPE is sent when you try to write to an unconnected pipe/socket. Installing a handler for the signal will make send() return an error instead.

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

Alternatively, you can disable SIGPIPE for a socket:

```
int n = 1;
setsockopt(thesocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NOSIGPIPE, &n, sizeof(n));
```

Also, the data amounts you're mentioning are not very high. Likely there's a bug somewhere that causes your connection to close unexpectedly, giving a SIGPIPE.

Comment: Note that SO_NOSIGPIPE isn't portable. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly

Answer (score 2):

SIGPIPE is raised because you are attempting to write to a socket that has been closed. This does indicate a probable bug so check your application as to why it is occurring and attempt to fix that first.

Attempting to just mask SIGPIPE is not a good idea because you don't really know where the signal is coming from and you may mask other sources of this error. In multi-threaded environments, signals are a horrible solution.

In the rare cases were you cannot avoid this, you can mask the signal on send. If you set the `MSG_NOSIGNAL` flag on `send()`/`sendto()`, it will prevent `SIGPIPE` being raised. If you do trigger this error, `send()` returns -1 and  `errno` will be set to `EPIPE`. Clean and easy. See `man send` for details.