# what does means this error "broken pipe"?

Tags: python, sockets, broken-pipe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TCP client-server SIGPIPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196971/tcp-client-server-sigpipe)

I would like know what does this error mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using sockets and Http protocol.

It simply means your TCP connection has been closed by the other end or broken due to some other reason. By broken it means a 3 way handshake is required again before starting data transfer. As mentioned in the comments, being on listening end i.e. server, you normally cannot initiate the connection. So should simply close this socket and proceed ahead.

However, if you were a client, you should probably call api similar to connect again and proceed once it is successful.

[Broken pipe on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181255/java-nio-what-does-ioexception-broken-pipe-mean)

Comment: As this HTTP and as this is the server end, he can't just redo the handshake. He should just abandon the response and the client.

Comment: Agreed. I meant handshake would be required again. Not referring to the listening end initiating it. Will edit to clarify that. Thanks