# Broken pipe when socket is closed

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I have a server/client app on a Linux box. If the server is not up when the client attempts to send a request, I get a SIGPIPE and the application terminates.

How can I check if the server is available on the socket before I try to write?

Also of note, I do not want to trap the SIGPIPE because the client is really part of a shared object that is used by many applications that may or may not already define their own signal handling methods.

Thanks

Comment: You can forbid local unix sockets. SIGPIPE is only generate for this type of socket. But that may hurt performance (a lot).

Comment: Another SO post might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly

Comment: You get SIGPIPE for inet stream sockets as well.

Comment: Would it be easier to do it "out-of-band", so to speak? E.g. have a `/var/run/server.pid` file or something that the client could check to see if the server was alive.

Comment: @Ilkka: You'd just introduce a race condition and make the error more rare.

Comment: I suggest changing the question title to something more descriptive. Maybe "How to handle SIGPIPE from a library without interfering with the main program"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass `MSG_NOSIGNAL` as flags to `send()`

Comment: MSG_NOSIGNAL is not portable.

Comment: @ukhardy: OP states linux in tags

Comment: It is definitely Linux only. I will play around with that and let you know. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed; `send` now returns -1 on fail rather than a SIGPIPE. Interestingly enough, I found no mention of `MSG_NOSIGNAL` in the man page for `send`.

Answer (score 0):

This [post](http://krokisplace.blogspot.com/2010/02/suppressing-sigpipe-in-library.html) by kroki describes what seems to be a good method.

To summarize it:

- Check if SIGPIPE is pending. Record that in a variable. If it is pending before we even start then someone else blocked SIGPIPE. In that case skip all the signal stuff below and just do the write.
- sigblock SIGPIPE.
- Do the write.
- Check if SIGPIPE is pending.
- If it is pending then sigtimedwait for it with zero timeout.
- Unblock SIGPIPE.