# How to run " ps cax | grep something " in Python?

Tags: python, command, pipe

How do I run a command with a pipe `|` in it?

The subprocess module seems complex...

Is there something like

```
output,error = `ps cax | grep something`
```

as in shell script?

Comment: Don't do this with `subprocess`.  It's much easier to do this with the shell.  Indeed, this is the one thing the shell does best.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

See [Replacing shell pipeline](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline):

```
import subprocess

proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'cax'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'python'], stdin=proc1.stdout,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

proc1.stdout.close() # Allow proc1 to receive a SIGPIPE if proc2 exits.
out, err = proc2.communicate()
print('out: {0}'.format(out))
print('err: {0}'.format(err))
```

PS. Using `shell=True` can be dangerous. See for example [the warning](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) in the docs.

---

There is also the [sh module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh) which can make subprocess scripting in Python a lot more pleasant:

```
import sh
print(sh.grep(sh.ps("cax"), 'something'))
```

Comment: Great reference to the sh module, I highly recommend it.

Comment: `sh.grep(sh.ps('aux', _piped=True), 'something')` - worked for me

Comment: @unutbu, Could you explain more detail why `proc1.stdout.close()` should be called?

Comment: @SangminKim: This appears to have been fixed or worked-around in Python3, but in
Python2.7 at least, if you were to 
spawn a long-running process such as `find / -print` in `proc1` without calling
`proc1.stdout.close()` and spawn a short-running command like `head` in `proc2`, then you would see `find / -print` is still running long
after the call to `head` has ended. Including `proc1.stdout.close()` allows `find` to
end soon after `head` finishes.

Comment: For more on SIGPIPE, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly#comment72630256_32597537), [this post](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/sigpipe_handling.html) and [this one too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8369506/190597).

Comment: @unutbu, Thank you for your answering. However, I am not clear on that. Thus I open another question on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48001819/3523935), since It is too long to write as a comment.

Comment: ImportError: No module named sh

Answer (score 24):

You've already accepted an answer, but:

Do you really *need* to use grep? I'd write something like:

```
import subprocess
ps = subprocess.Popen(('ps', 'cax'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = ps.communicate()[0]
for line in output.split('\n'):
    if 'something' in line:
        ...
```

This has the advantages of not involving `shell=True` and its riskiness, doesn't fork off a separate grep process, and looks an awful lot like the kind of Python you'd write to process data file-like objects.

Comment: for me, `output` was a [byte] and had to use it like `str(output).split("\\n")`

Answer (score 12):

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen("ps cax | grep something",
                             shell=True,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           )
stdout_list = process.communicate()[0].split('\n')
```

Comment: something in grep something would be a variable, should I construct the "ps cax | grep something" string with variable to run it? or is there other way of doing it?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting or http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-formatting. Basically, `'grep %s` % variable`.

Comment: @Eugene: You can construct the string using a variable, but be careful about where the variable is coming from. I.e. make sure it's not from a user who could make "something" into `"something; rm -rf /"`. Building expressions to run with shell=True is a possible security risk.

Answer (score 6):

Drop that 'ps' subprocess and back away slowly! :)

Use the [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil/) module instead.

Comment: I want to use psutil, but this answer isn't very helpful without showing how it would be done.

Comment: pls share example

Comment: `import psutil; for proc in psutil.process_iter(): cmdline = " ".join(proc.cmdline()); if something in cmdline: break`

Answer (score 4):

```
import os

os.system('ps -cax|grep something')
```

If you wanna replace grep argument with some variable:

```
os.system('ps -cax|grep '+your_var)
```

Comment: @Kirk Strauser, can't you get the output? I have testd it both in interactive python interpreter and running it as script, it works as expected(my python version is 2.7.1,if it helps)

Comment: `os.system` only returns the int exit code of the subprocess. If you're running it at an interactive prompt and seeing the output of ps, it's because ps is writing to stout. Python isn't actually capturing that output. Try it yourself: run `a = os.system('ls')`. You'll still see the output of ls, and `a` will be 0 (assuming ls didn't fail for some reason).

Comment: This is unsafe. If `your_var` is set by someone else, this code lets them run any command they want. For example `your_var = "a; echo you got hacked"`