# Subprocess call with pipe in it

Tags: python, subprocess

How would I do the following subprocess command in python?

```
$ ps aux|grep python

>>> subprocess.check_output(['ps', 'aux', 'grep', 'python']) ?
```

Comment: You need to create two subprocesses, one for `ps aux`, the other for `grep python`. Connect the output pipe of the first to the input pipe of the second.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780035/python-how-to-run-ps-cax-grep-something-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
ps = subprocess.Popen(('ps', 'aux'), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = subprocess.check_output(('grep', 'python'), stdin=ps.stdout)
ps.wait()

print output
```