# How to check the process with subprocess in Python 2.6?

Tags: python

I have a shell script which I used to run for a quick process check mechanism in my Linux environment. Below is just one piece of code which I am using.

How we can achieve the same in Python? I just searched and found to use the "subprocess" module for this purpose, will that be good enough?

```
Check_ntp () {
    echo "Checking the NTP Service Status on $(uname -n)"
    ps -e | grep ntp > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "Service Status:  NTP Service is Running"
    else
    echo "Service Status:  NTP Service is Not Running"
    fi
    }
```

### Update

I found the answer to my question myself:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
PSNTP = subprocess.call('ps -e| grep ntp > /dev/null 2>&1', shell=True)
if PSNTP == 0:
    print "Status:  NTP Service is Running"
else:
   print "Status:  NTP Service is not Runningg"

PSNSCD = subprocess.call('ps -e | grep nscd > /dev/null 2>&1', shell=True)
if PSNSCD == 0:
   print "Status:  NSCD Service is Running"
else:
   print "Status:  NSCD Service is not Running"
```

Comment: I don't know what any of that code is doing but I bet [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) would be useful here.

Comment: @Kevin   This is code is just doing the process check , there is a process called NTP in UNIX/Linux , this is just checking the validity of that process whether its ruining or not using the UNix/Linux "ps -e" command.

Comment: Don't put your answer in the question. The question is a question, not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how do it with [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) but using [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) may do the job:

```
import subprocess

cmd1 = ['ps', '-e'] 
cmd2 = ['grep', 'ntp']

proc1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd1,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(cmd2,stdin=proc1.stdout,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

proc1.stdout.close() # Allow proc1 to receive a SIGPIPE if proc2 exits.
out, err=proc2.communicate()

if out:
    print "Service Status:  NTP Service is Running"
else:
    print "Service Status:  NTP Service is Not Running"

# print('out: {0}'.format(out)) # optionally view output
# print('err: {0}'.format(err)) # and any errors
```

Comment: @downshit    Thanks for your answer, though i got the way to do it at the same time i see your answer is really commendable as well.

Can you please explain the `if out:` statement how its working.

Comment: @Karn, very welcome. `if out:` is a check to see if any response was received from `proc2.communicate()` method (the line before `if out:`) which is [Popen.communicate()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) which `communicate() returns a tuple (stdoutdata, stderrdata).".

Comment: So `out` is a variable that got assigned to `index[0]` of that response tuple: `stdoutdata`, and likewise variable `err` got assigned to index[1]: `stderrdata`. Since we want to check if `stdoutdata` was received we do an `if` check, `if out:` which is the same as `if proc2.communicate()[0]:` the first index of the `subprocess.Popen().communicate()` response.

Comment: By the way, I borrowed most of my answer from this answer: [How to run “ ps cax | grep something ” in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780035/how-to-run-ps-cax-grep-something-in-python)

Comment: awesome , sounds good one.