# Unknown shorthand flag: 'E' in -E

Tags: python

I am trying to execute a `bash` command in `python`

The bash command I want to execute is: `kubectl get ns | grep -E '(^|\s)OK($|\s)'`

And in python I do this like this:

```
is_namespace_exists = subprocess.call(["kubectl", "get", "ns", "|", "grep", "-E", "\'(^|\s)"+NAMESPACE+"($|\s)\'"])
```

and

```
is_namespace_exists = subprocess.call(["kubectl", "get", "ns", "|", "grep", "-E", "'(^|\s)"+NAMESPACE+"($|\s)'"])
```

But I get this error:

> unknown shorthand flag: 'E' in -E

Can someone tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: when I execute this in a normal terminal it works. When I execute it using the python it doesn't.

Comment: I retract my previous comment. It's interpreted as argument to `kubectl`, since `|` has no meaning to `subprocess`. It only has a meaning in a shell. `subprocess` doesn't parse the command through a shell.

Comment: So what I can do about this? I need that pipe (`|`) there

Comment: You need to use `shell=True` in your `subprocess.call` call, and pass it a string rather than a list.

Comment: I'd probably prefer to just execute `['kubectl', 'get', 'ns']`, and do the tiny bit of string processing in Python afterwards.

Comment: I am new to python, can you provide me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
import subprocess

NAMESPACE = "..."  # Define NAMESPACE variable here

proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['kubectl', 'get', 'ns'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(["grep", "-E", "\'(^|\s)"+NAMESPACE+"($|\s)\'"], stdin=proc1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

proc1.stdout.close() # Allow proc1 to receive a SIGPIPE if proc2 exits.
out, err = proc2.communicate()
print('out: {0}'.format(out))
print('err: {0}'.format(err))
```

Basically an adaptation of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780035/how-to-run-ps-cax-grep-something-in-python). Adapt according to your needs.