# Python - how to add "pipe" in exec_cmd method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have my python function which works perfectly in both windows and linux, when executing the command and processing the output.

```
def exec_cmd(cmd, fail=True):

    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        return output
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
        logging.info(msg)
```

E.g.:

```
output = exec_cmd(['accurev', 'stat', '-a'], fail=False)
```

Now I would need to add "pipe" in order to grep the output within the command immediately.

Command:

```
accurev stat -a | find "(elink)"
```

Can you tell me how I can do it?
Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332268/how-to-use-subprocess-command-with-pipes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780035/how-to-run-ps-cax-grep-something-in-python