# App crashes with SIGPIPE exception after doing a wrong connection to FTP server

Tags: ipad, sockets, ftp, handler, sigpipe

I try to make an app that can make a connection into a FTP server. I've use Chilkat library to do this connection. The problem is, I want to test my app and make a wrong connection. So i make a connection into my FTP server, but using SSL connection (base on chilkat example in [Chilkat sample code for implicit SSL connection](http://www.example-code.com/objc/ftp_ImplicitSSL.asp))

FYI, I am not setting SSL in my FTP server. After I run my code on device, the app crashed, and the debugger showed SIGPIPE. I know SIGPIPE is because I made a wrong socket connection, but I dont know how to handle it. I have read an article about [uncaught exception on this link](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/handling-unhandled-exceptions-and.html), but I don't know how to implement these.

Can somebody tell me, **how to handle these SIGPIPE exceptions?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this answer: [Prevent Sigpipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly)

When you ignore sigpipes your app won't crash anymore when recieving a sigpipe.