# How to avoid a broken pipe?

Tags: c, sockets

I try to develop a chat application in c. I use sockets and `select()`.
But if i close the server before the client, the client have a message "Broken Pipe".
I used select(), but i didn't know how to avoid it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SIGPIPEs (or handle them properly)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly)

Comment: Don't just close the pipe, say goodbye nicely.  So that the other end knows to close it too.

Answer (score 5):

You can disable the signal:

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

Though the chosen answer was to ignore signal process wide, there are other alternatives:

Using send function with MSG_NOSIGNAL:

```
 send(con, buff_enviar+enviado, length-enviado, MSG_NOSIGNAL);
```

Disabling SIGPIPE on socket level (not available on all kernels):

```
int flag = 1;
setsockopt(con, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NOSIGPIPE, &flag, sizeof(flag));
```

Disabling SIGPIPE for caller thread (you can restore it after):

```
sigset_t set;
sigemptyset (&set);
sigaddset (&set, SIGPIPE);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Register a handler for the PIPE signal (and maybe ignore the signal).

Comment: is there another way ? i don't want to catch the signal pipe

Comment: @heruma: You can use `SIG_IGN` to ignore `SIGPIPE`. Just read a manual page or something.. Some APIs also support extra pipe options to disable delivering a `SIGPIPE` from the kernel. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly