# Is there any case that web browser has no interest in my poor web server-response?

Tags: c, sockets

**Question**

I have implemented web server in C. But web server often receives sigpipe signal and dies. I'd like to understand why sigpipe error occurs. I have just learned that sigpipe is said to occur if client closes socket earlier than server. But I think there is not possibility that client close socket earlier, since my server do not sends additional header information. for example, cache information, date information, etc.
So, **I'm curious** if there is any case that web browser has no interest in my poor web server-response. And **how client can close socket earlier than server?**

**Some scenario**

my server wait for request message for client. it then parse only status line.
it then send response message to browser(client).

if the requested file is HTML document, server sends the following response message. That is, server writes HTML text into socket, not existing file on hard disk.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close

<html file>
```

if the requested file is *.jpg, *.gif, or *.ico, server sends the following message.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: close
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-length: <file size>
Content-Type:image/jpg, gif or x-icon

<some binary information for image>
```

Any help would be awesome. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SIGPIPEs (or handle them properly)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly)

Comment: Yes. one solution is to ignore sigpipe signal. But I also curious if there is any case that web browser has no interest in my server response and if how browser can close socket earlier than server.

Comment: Use `telnet` on the client side to debug you server's basics. Then go and read the http specs and simulate a web-browser (still using `telnet`). If those tests succeeded **then** use your web-browser.

Comment: specs is not important now. Client sends request for corresponding file. but client closes socket earlier.  I'm going to post request message soon.