# Program received signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe

Tags: c, sockets, gdb, pthreads, sigpipe

I write a client program based on posix sockets. The program creates multiple threads and is going to lock the server. But during debug in gdb time the program gives an info (error)

> ```
> (gdb) n
> Program received signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe. [Switching to Thread 0xb74c0b40 (LWP 4864)] 0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall () 
> (gdb)
> ```

Here's the code:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int get_hostname_by_ip(char* h , char* ip)
{
    struct hostent *he;
    struct in_addr **addr_list;
    int i;

    if ((he = gethostbyname(h)) == NULL) 
    {
        perror("gethostbyname");
        return 1;
    }
    addr_list = (struct in_addr **) he->h_addr_list;
    for(i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++) 
    {
        strcpy(ip , inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]) );
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

void client(char* h, int s)
{
    int fd;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    char ch[]="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";
    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    char* ip = new char[20];
    get_hostname_by_ip(h, ip);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip);
    int port = 80;
    addr.sin_port=htons(port);
    if(connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) 
    {
        perror("connect error");
        return;
    }
    while(1)
    {
        if(send(fd, ch, sizeof(ch), 0) < 0)
        {   
            perror("send");
        }
    }
    //char buffer[1024];
    //if(recv(fd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0) < 0)
    //{ 
    //  perror("recive");
    //}

    //printf("nReply from Server: %s\n", buffer);
    close(fd);
}

struct info
{
    char* h;
    int c;
};


void* thread_entry_point(void* i)
{
    info* in = (info*)i;
    client(in->h, in->c);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int s = atoi(argv[2]);
    pthread_t t[s];
    info in = {argv[1], s};
    for(int i = 0; i < s; ++i)
    {
        pthread_create(&t[i], NULL, thread_entry_point, (void*)&in);
    }
    pthread_join(t[0], NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

What it is and what to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent SIGPIPEs (or handle them properly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The process received a `SIGPIPE`. The default behaviour for this signal is to end the process.

A `SIGPIPE` is sent to a process if it tried to write to a socket that had been shutdown for writing or isn't connected (anymore).

To avoid that the program ends in this case, you could either

- make the process ignore `SIGPIPE`

  ```
  #include <signal.h>

  int main(void)
  {
    sigaction(SIGPIPE, &(struct sigaction){SIG_IGN}, NULL);

    ...
  ```

  or
- install an explicit handler for `SIGPIPE` (typically doing nothing):

  ```
  #include <signal.h>

  void sigpipe_handler(int unused)
  {
  }

  int main(void)
  {
    sigaction(SIGPIPE, &(struct sigaction){sigpipe_handler}, NULL);

    ...
  ```

In both cases `send*()`/`write()` would return `-1` and set `errno` to `EPIPE`.

Comment: would this work?

if(signal(SIGPIPE, signalHandler) == EINVAL) 

how would I get the error -1 and EPIPE.

Comment: @Dreyfus15: To clarify uncertainties on how to sert up signal handlers please post another question on this.

Answer (score 45):

When debugging with 'gdb', it is possible to manually disable SIGPIPE as follows:

(gdb) handle SIGPIPE nostop

Comment: It's actually `handle SIGPIPE nostop noprint pass`

Comment: That will then terminate the program instead of stopping in gdb (unless the program ignores SIGPIPE or installed a handler for it, as per the accepted answer).

Answer (score 12):

A workaround for SIGPIPE, you can ignore this signal by this code:

```
#include <signal.h>

/* Catch Signal Handler functio */
void signal_callback_handler(int signum){

        printf("Caught signal SIGPIPE %d\n",signum);
}
```

in your code (main or globally)

```
/* Catch Signal Handler SIGPIPE */
signal(SIGPIPE, signal_callback_handler);
```

Comment: Your signal handler for SIGPIPE writes a message out to stdout. But suppose writing to stdout is what caused the SIGPIPE in the first place...?

Comment: Using non-reentrant stdio from signal handlers is not safe.

Comment: It's true that you have to worry about reentrant code if you are doing a printf() in the handler.  However seeing it's just an example I feel a printf() is fine, just throw a signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL); before the printf() and you should be fine.

Comment: or you could just ignore it directly without providing any fake handler, i.e. `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);`

Answer (score 9):

You have written to a connection that has already been closed by the peer.

Answer (score 5):

I sort of experienced the same problem and it let me to this SO post. I got sporadic SIGPIPE signals causing crashes of my fastcgi C program run by nginx. I tried to `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);` without luck, it kept crashing.

The reason was that nginx's temp dir had a permission problem. Fixing the permissions solved the SIGPIPE problem. [Details here on how to fix](https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/13-permission-denied-while-reading-upstream-using-nginx/) and [more here](https://serverfault.com/questions/235154/permission-denied-while-reading-upstream).