# What does signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN); do?

Tags: c, unix, signals

I know the individual uses of `SIGPIPE` and `SIGIGN`.

What does

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

exactly do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Program received signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935446/program-received-signal-sigpipe-broken-pipe)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

simply ignores the signal `SIGPIPE`. Passing `SIG_IGN` as *handler* ignores a given signal (except the signals `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` which can't caught or ignored).

As an aside, it's generally recommended to use [`sigaction(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html) over [`signal(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) as `sigaction` offers better control and also don't need to "reset" the handler on some systems (which follow the System V signal behaviour).

Comment: Can we also unset this handler, if it was already set before?

Comment: You can call signal(2) again to reset it. For example, to reset it to default behaviour, call: `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL);`.

Comment: `signal()` also returns the previously installed handler. So a clean reset should be : `void (*old)(int); old = signal(some_signal,some_handler); ... signal(some_signal,old);`. Anyway, `signal` is the old (considered obsolete) interface, you should use `sigaction` is place.

Comment: How to do something in code right after you ignored SIGPIPE signal like ` printf("SIGPIPE signal detected!") `

Comment: not sure I understand "ignores a given signal ignores it "

Comment: @David天宇Wong Hi, fixed it. Thanks.