# catching client exit from server on socket programing

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

I need some insight on socket error handling in c++ (or c).
I am testing a simple client and server program like under:

```
 .....
 while (1) { // server keeps sending strings to client
     sprintf(jsonStr, "{ \"%d: Hello\": \"world!\" } \n", index++);
     size = send(newsockfd, jsonStr, strlen(jsonStr), 0);
     if (size == -1) {
       error("ERROR on send");
     }
     sleep(1);
 }
 .....
```

While client is receiving strings from server, if I  kill client, server also exits without any message.
Is this expected? How can I catch it instead of exiting? I tried "try" and "catch" but wasn't able to catch.
With java, I get the "Broken pipe" SocketException using DataOutputStream.writeUTF().
I have tested on Mac and Linux and their results were same.

I use example codes from: https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/sockets_server_client.php

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to send on a broken socket will raise a SIGPIPE signal. The default behavior when receiving a SIGPIPE is to terminate the process (which is the behavior you are observing).

You can fix this by:

- Ignoring the signal (works on any platform)
- Setting the `SO_NOSIGPIPE` socket option (Mac/BSD only)
- Passing the `MSG_NOSIGNAL` flag to send (Linux only)

send should then return -1 with errno set to EPIPE if a write is performed on a broken socket.

For further details on handling SIGPIPE, see:

- [How to prevent SIGPIPEs (or handle them properly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly)
- [Program received signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935446/program-received-signal-sigpipe-broken-pipe)