# SIGPIPE (OSX) and disconnected sockets?

Tags: c, xcode, macos, sockets, sigpipe

I'm working on an app which connects to a server via TCP.

If the socket for whatever reason is closed, I end up in the SIGPIPE handler.

What do I do so that recv and send just returns an error on a disconnected/closed socket?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent SIGPIPEs (or handle them properly)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly)

Comment: I read this post, but nothing in that post seems to fix the issue I'm having. I'm probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I've found ignoring SIGPIPE ineffective on OS X.  Use SO_NOSIGPIPE instead.  Note this is set on the socket once, as opposed to MSG_NOSIGNAL which is requested in each call to send().

```
int socket = accept (...); /* (or however you're getting the socket) */
int option_value = 1; /* Set NOSIGPIPE to ON */
if (setsockopt (socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NOSIGPIPE, &option_value, sizeof (option_value)) < 0) {
    perror ("setsockopt(,,SO_NOSIGPIPE)");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`SIG_IGN` the signal rather than handling it.  `send` will return -1 and errno will be set to EPIPE.

Comment: What about recv? This --> signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN) doesn't seem to help. I still get a SIGPIPE. I guess recv just blocks until the socket is closed? If the connection is dropped for whatever reason, what will recv return? Just 0?

Comment: `read()` and `recv()`  return `0` if the peer closed or shut down the connection. See `man read` or `man recv` for details. If still unclear pose another question on this differnt topic.

Comment: As alk said you don't have to worry about sigpipe with recv.  If the socket peer closed you will get the normal shutdown notification of a zero read.  The `signal` system call semantics are non-standard across platforms.  On linux you can coax it to behave the way you want through feature test macros but I don't know what OSX defaults to.  Better to use `sigaction` and I see that alk has left an answer describing how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

To ignore a signal set the signal handler to `SIG_IGN` doing so:

```
struct sigaction sa;
memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));

sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;

if (-1 == sigaction(SIGPIPE, &sa, NULL))
{
  perror("sigaction() failed");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring SIGPIPE as described in other answers (ie. `signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);`) worked for me on OS X. Also be sure to test outside a debugger as it says in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly#comment57477933_108192). I was debugging with `lldb` and its signal handling was terminating my program with SIGPIPE even though I'd ignored that signal. Testing outside of `lldb` worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

use  signal handler or ignore it

```
#include <signal.h>
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

while writing to a socket first check if socket fd is positive or not in program. Externally you should check that you are sending pointer of a valid socket

Comment: did you use #include <signal.h>??

Comment: @user1884325: If using `signal()` you most probably need to reapply the handler after having been used once. Do not use `signal` use sigaction()`.

Comment: yes sigaction is more descriptive and more useful but POSIX.1 and signal is basic but it is a feature of ISO C

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore `SIGPIPE`

```
 #include <signal.h>

signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

Or you can use signal handler.

```
signal(SIGPIPE, handler);
void handler(int signal)
{   
    //("Signal caught");

}
```

Comment: Do not `printf()` from signl handlers, as `printf()` is not guaranteed to be signal safe.