# Handle a signal as error

Tags: c, sockets, signals

Hi I'm programming a threaded socket program, The program may receive a `SIGPIPE` signal and will exit, If I catch the signal and ignore it the program will have undefined behavior because I don't know how to handle this as error, How can I catch a signal and notify the current position of the code that it needs to return from a function with error code so the program flow will continue as normal, I want to threat the `SIGPIPE` as it is error in read/write syscalls, cause i know how to handle read/write errors when I receive them.

```
{
    signal(SIGPIPE,sig_handler);
}

void sig_handler(int signo)
{
  if (signo == SIGPIPE){
    printf("hi\n");

  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent SIGPIPEs (or handle them properly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly)

Answer (score 2):

if you want to ignore the SIGPIPE and handle the error directly in your code. 
but signal handlers in C have many restrictions .
The most easy way is to set the SIGPIPE handler to SIG_IGN. This will prevent any socket write from causing a SIGPIPE signal.
To ignore the SIGPIPE signal, use the following code:

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

OR
to handle this try this:

```
#include <signal.h>
/* Catch Signal Handler functio */
void signal_handler(int signum)
{
 printf("Caught signal SIGPIPE %d\n",signum);
}
```

and In program:

```
/* Catch Signal Handler SIGPIPE */
signal(SIGPIPE, signal_callback_handler);
```

Another methode is that set the socket options while creating the socket: change the socket so it never generates SIGPIPE on write().

```
int num = 1;
setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_NOSIGPIPE, (void *)&num, sizeof(int));
```

Comment: You should **not** call printf() from within a signal handler.

Comment: we can set a flag in signal handler and can monitor that flag in main programme.   for example: declare this flag globly static int alarm = 0; in signal handler : alarm = 1; // set flag       and in main programme check this flag