# Broken Pipe for C-Socket. How to only keep server running?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, client-server, sigpipe

In a simple program where I'm trying to send command-line inputs from client to server, I keep getting a "Broken Pipe" for the server side. I send a string to the server and the server returns the string as lower-case to the client.

#### Server:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{

    char str[100];
    int listen_fd, comm_fd;

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero( &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(37892);

    bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    listen(listen_fd, 10);

    comm_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr*) NULL, NULL);

    while(1){
                bzero( str, 100);
                read(comm_fd,str,100);
                for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++){

                        str[i] = tolower(str[i]);

                }
                printf("Echoing back - %s",str);
                write(comm_fd, str, strlen(str)+1);
        }
}
```

#### Client

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int sockfd,n;
    char sendline[100];
    char recvline[100];
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    bzero(&servaddr,sizeof servaddr);

    servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port=htons(37892);

    inet_pton(AF_INET,"127.0.0.1",&(servaddr.sin_addr));

    connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));


    if(argc==1) printf("\nNo arguments");

    if (1){
        {
                bzero( sendline, 100);
                bzero( recvline, 100);
                strcpy(sendline, argv[1]);
                write(sockfd,sendline,strlen(sendline)+1);
                read(sockfd,recvline,100);
                printf("%s",recvline);
         }
     }
}
```

The problem I found was that when the client's side is done sending the string, the command line input does not work like `fgets()` where the loop will wait for another user input. If I change the `if(1)` in the client's side to a `while(1)`, it will obviously run an infinite loop as no new inputs are being added. 
The dilemma is, how would I be able to keep the server's side running to continuously return the string to the client while processing single requests from the command line on the client's side?

Comment: You aren't paying attention to what `read()` and `write()` return, which is always a serious problem.  You don't error check `socket()` or `connect()` (or `bind()` or `accept()`) either — ditto.  You copy `argv[1]` into `sendline` which really isn't necessary, but if you do the copying, you must check there's enough space.   Although the `read()` in the client is 'safe', you need to know how many bytes were received so you can print the correct number; you might have read 100 of 120 bytes, and the string won't be null-terminate.  You have to be very, very careful!

Comment: To answer the headline question, you'd have to handle SIGPIPE errors — or ignore them and pay attention to error returns from `write()`.  You can then close the connection and loop back for the next one.  You also aren't closing any file descriptors, so sooner or later you'll run out of them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent SIGPIPEs (or handle them properly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program has two problems:

1) `read()` works differently than you think:

Normally `read()` will read up to a certain number of **bytes** from some file or stream (e.g. socket).

Because `read()` does not distinguish between different types of bytes (e.g. letters, the end-of-line marker or even the NUL byte) `read()` will not work like `fgets()` (reading line-wise).

`read()` is also allowed to "split" the data: If you do a `write(..."Hello\n"...)` on the client the server may receive `"Hel"` the first time you call `read()` and the next time it receives `"lo\n"`.

And of course `read()` can concatenate data: Call `write(..."Hello\n"...)` and `write(..."World\n"...)` on the client and one single `read()` call may receive `"Hello\nWorld\n"`.

And of course both effects may appear at the same time and you have to call `read()` three times receiving `"Hel"`, `"lo\nWo"` and `"rld\n"`.

TTYs (= the console (keyboard) and serial ports) have a special feature (which may be switched off) that makes the `read()` call behave like `fgets()`. However **only** TTYs have such a feature!

In the case of sockets `read()` will always wait for at least one byte to be received and return the (positive) number of bytes received as long as the connection is alive. As soon as `read()` returns zero or a negative value the connection has been dropped.

You have to use a `while` loop that processes data until the connection has been dropped.

You'll have to check the data received by `read()` if it contains the NUL byte to detect the "end" of the data - if "your" data is terminated by a NUL byte.

2) As soon as the client drops the connection the handle returned by `accept()` is useless.

You should close that handle to save memory and file descriptors (there is a limit on how many file descriptors you can have open at one time).

Then you have to call `accept()` again to wait for the client to establish a new connection.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your client sends one request and reads one response.
2. It then exits without closing the socket.
3. Your server runs in a loop reading requests and sending responses.
4. Your server ignores end of stream.
5. Little or none of this code is error-checked.