C - using poll() to check socket state works in debug mode, does not in regular run
I want to check the state of the socket before writing into it, because without checking my code dumps on broken pipe. I am using function poll() as follows:
    struct pollfd pfds[1];
    pfds[0].fd = sock_fd;
    pfds[0].events = POLLOUT;

    if (poll(pfds, 1, -1) == -1) {
        printf("Cannot check status of socket\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (pfds[0].revents & POLLOUT) {
        if (write(sock_fd, token, 1) != 1) {
        printf("Could not write to socket\n");
            token[0] = 0x02;
            return_code = -1;
            break;
        }
    }

When I debug it, the condition pfds[0].revents & POLLOUT is evaluated as true. When I run it without debug mode it is always evaluated as false.
The socket is created as follows:
if ( socketpair( AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, fds ) == -1 )
    err( 1, "socketpair" );

I tried sleep(1) before calling function poll() but without success.
What else can I try to make this work? I suspect that this has something to do with incorrect timing but have no idea what to try.

Why not just check for errno == EPIPE when you try to write to the pipe?

It's a school assignment and I'm suppose to check with poll before writing into socket. I'm getting broken pipe either way but when I use poll it works at least in debugger

I can't think of a reason why this would work differently in the debugger.

Please show minimal reproducible example with part where you create socket pair. SIGPIPE on Unix socket occurs when remote peer is closed. You can ignore the signal by setting it's handler to SIG_IGN or by using send() with MSG_NOSIGNAL flag instead of write(). poll() also may be used to check if remote peer has closed connection by checking POLLERR bit. POLLOUT bit just indicates that write() or send() would not block on blocking socket.

UPD: POLLERR is not set when other peer has closed connection. I confused it with EPOLLERR for epoll_wait(). Anyway, poll() is not supposed to avoid SIGPIPE. Perhaps you closed second descriptor of a pair somewhere before write.

Logical error: Get the return status of write() or send(), because only some data may be sent. On success it tells the number of bytes sent. Then remove these number of bytes from output buffer.

You can get rid of the broken pipe signal quite easily:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly

Probably you can confirm other return events, pfds[0].revents & POLLERR to check "Error condition on socket", pfds[0].revents & POLLHUP to check "Socket has been disconnected", pfds[0].revents & POLLNVAL to check "Invalid request: the fd is not open"

You should be checking the return value of poll() for > 0, not != -1, before checking the contents of pfds.
